# In OS X how to avoid typing passwords twice if FileVault 2 is enabled?

Tags: macos, mac, backup, passwords, filevault

After erasing the startup volume with encryption enabled (FileVault 2) and restoring the previous backup, I found myself needing to type passwords twice: the first one is to unlock the drive and the second is to log in the system.

Is there a way to save one typing of the passwords? Automatic log-in?

Thanks!

Comment: You may have to modify your keychain, associating the FileVault with the new user account.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, parallels desktop was causing the issue (not kidding, see this post [enter link description here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24157/filevault2-asking-for-password-twice)). I uninstalled it and used Virtualbox instead…